# [Autoware] What the magic number 3.6 mean?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, experts.
What the magic number 3.6 on [astar_avoid.cpp](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_planning/-/blob/master/waypoint_planner/src/astar_avoid/astar_avoid.cpp#L175) mean?

`avoid_start_velocity_ / 3.6`

the avoid_velocity value is a flag to switch the planning logic like this.

```
bool avoid_velocity = (current_velocity_.twist.linear.x < avoid_start_velocity_ / 3.6);  
....
else if (state_ == AstarAvoid::STATE::STOPPING)
{
  bool replan = ((ros::WallTime::now() - start_plan_time).toSec() > replan_interval_);

  if (!found_obstacle)
  {
    ROS_INFO("STOPPING -> RELAYING, Obstacle disappers");
    state_ = AstarAvoid::STATE::RELAYING;
  }
  else if (replan && avoid_velocity)
  {
    ROS_INFO("STOPPING -> PLANNING, Start A* planning");
    state_ = AstarAvoid::STATE::PLANNING;
  }
}
```

I couldn't understand why it have to be 3.6.
Does it have a reason mathmatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352573/%5Bautoware%5D-what-the-magic-number-3.6-mean?/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's from the conversion between mps and kmph.
36 kmph = 36000m / 3600s = 10 mps, so mps = kmph / 3.6

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosli](https://answers.ros.org/users/64427/rosli/) on 2020-12-09**:
did you use astar_navi? have you succesed? i meet some trouble!you can see my problem。do you have any suggestion?thanks you !!!!